# Development environment for Wordpress with Docker incl. FTP access

Tags: wordpress, docker, ftp

I would like to know if it is possible to provide a local development environment for Wordpress, where the data can be uploaded via FTP?

I already got the official Docker image of Wordpress running:

```
docker run --name wordpress-db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
docker run --name wordpress --link wordpress-db:mysql -p 8080:80 -d wordpress
```

Next, I'm trying to use an FTP Docker image. After a short search, I chose `metabrainz/docker-anon-ftp`. But I do not have to continue using this image if there are better ones. I have extended my commands as follows:

```
docker run --name wordpress --link wordpress-db:mysql -p 8080:80 -v /wordpress-volume:/var/www/html/wp-content -d wordpress
docker run --name wordpress-ftp -p 20-21:20-21 -p 65500-65515:65500-65515 -v /wordpress-volume:/var/www/html/wp-content -d metabrainz/docker-anon-ftp
```

Now I have the problem that the FTP server is reachable, but does not provide me with any content. 
What did I do wrong? Can someone give me the commands with which I can upload files (from my IDE) into Wordpress via FTP?